# Ionic2 tabs - how to change selected tab's color?

Tags: ionic2

Like in the title, I want to change the background-color of selected tab. I didn't find  any variable allowing this in the documentation. (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/). How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
#tab-t1-0[aria-selected=true] {
     background-color: red;
     color: #000;
}
```

**0** is the number of tab.

Answer (score 5):

For Ionic 2 & 3

Overwrite this class in your page scss file.

```
.tabs-md .tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
    color: #fff; /*your  text color */
    background: #808080; /* your background color*/
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks, @AbhishekTomar for letting me know. Will update answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

The official way would be:

Change in your `theme/variables.scss`

Active icon for tabs on **android** is:

`$tabs-md-tab-icon-color-active: red;`

On iOS

`$tabs-ios-tab-icon-color-active: red;`

Check out [Sass variables for ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#sass-variables)

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the solution but still any other developers who are still searching the easiest and flexible way to do it, you can follow these easy steps to achieve it -

Add this extralight scss variable with base and contrast property in the "variables.scss" file and add color="extralight" attribute in ion-tabs html tag -

```css
$colors: (
  primary:    #00a7ff,
  secondary:  #00edc5,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  extralight: (
    base: #ffffff,
    contrast: #4a4a4a
  )
);

$tabs-ios-tab-text-color-active:  #00a7ff !important;
$tabs-md-tab-text-color-active:   #00a7ff !important;
$tabs-md-tab-icon-color-active :  #00a7ff !important;
$tabs-ios-tab-icon-color-active :  #00a7ff !important;
```

```html
<ion-tabs color="extralight">
    <ion-tab [root]="complaintRoot" tabTitle="Complaint" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="paymentRoot" tabTitle="Payment" tabIcon="card"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

That's it, now you are done. ☺

Answer (score 1):

Setting and flipping a class.

f.e. in your constructor set:

```
document.getElementById("tab1").className = "tab";
document.getElementById("tab2").className = "tab";
document.getElementById("tab3").className = "tab active";
```

and setting some css

```
tab.active{
  background-color: black;
}
```

But if you want to override ionic's variables you should use

```
$colors(
  'primary': '#ffffff'
)
```

and setting in your html

```
<!-- ionic2 beta (using angular 2.0.0-RC.4)-->
<yourTab primary> 

<!-- or when using ionic2 RC0 (using angular 2.0.x) -->
<yourTab color="primary">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that worked for me,

For android,

```
.tabs-md[tabsLayout=icon-hide] .tab-button,
.tabs-md[tabsLayout=title-hide] .tab-button,
.tabs-md .tab-button.icon-only,
.tabs-md .tab-button.has-title-only {
    font-weight: 900 !important; 
}
.tabs-md .tab-button[aria-selected=true] .tab-button-text {
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

For ios,

```
.tabs-ios[tabsLayout=icon-hide] .tab-button,
    .tabs-ios[tabsLayout=title-hide] .tab-button,
    .tabs-ios .tab-button.icon-only,
    .tabs-ios .tab-button.has-title-only {
        font-weight: 900 !important; 
    }
    .tabs-ios .tab-button[aria-selected=true] .tab-button-text {
        -webkit-transform: none !important;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to;

$colors(
  'primary': '#83717B'
)